# Erlang 512 hash not matching python 512 hash

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, erlang, sha512

I'm trying to duplicate the following python code in Erlang:

```
python -c "import random,string,crypt;
print crypt.crypt('example', '\$6\$5H0QpwprRiJQR19Y\$')"

OUTPUT: $6$5H0QpwprRiJQR19Y$B8EBtKxKU4Poxi.qLsL/t7uoriHX/cdnn9kT7kTsUIvwKPR6oJLOl8NAH8vPT.BNPdEY7a4.rz8YhziecWQ6I/
```

From reading online:

- $6$ indicates this is a 512 hash
- '5H0QpwprRiJQR19Y' is the salt for the hash
- in the above code the passphase is 'example'

My current erlang code is below:

```
crypto:hash(sha512, "example5H0QpwprRiJQR19Y")
```

Which produces:

```
<<167,181,70,20,213,141,24,28,86,204,170,121,182,75,217,3,51,222,3,209,44,43,34,243,130,214,247,156,149,150,162,81,200,207,103,85,60,202,37,189,30,25,128,221,61,79,146,86,225,126,35,85,4,161,156,152,8,6,90,17,207,229,235,241>>
```

I've tried manipulating the return but can't get them to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find an implementation of crypt in Erlang, only wrappers such as [this one](https://github.com/msantos/crypt). Generally lower level languages like C are better at the task of repeated hashing than a higher level language such as Erlang. So using this guarantees compatibility and is faster than implementing it yourself.

If you want to implement it yourself, then you can, by using the specification [here](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt). Note that this is one of the most shitty password hashes to understand and implement around, so this is probably not for the uninitiated. You'd better just take an existing code from another language and translate that.